# Почему после правильного ввода пароля вместо одного пишет два раза: "Подтвердите действие"?

Tags: javascript, операторы

```js
var mega;
var war;
var dzen=prompt('Кто пришёл?',''); 
if (dzen=='Админ') {

 war=prompt('Введите пароль.','');

 if (war==null) 
 {
  mega='Вход отменён.';
 }
 else if (war=='Чёрный властелин') 
 {
  mega='Добро пожаловать!';
 }
 else 
 {
  mega='Пароль не верен.';
 }
 alert(mega);
}
else if (dzen==null) 
{
 war='Вход отменён';
}
else 
{
 war='Я вас не знаю!';
}
alert(war);
```

Comment: У вас `alert(war)`

Comment: У вас в коде два alert - вот два раза и пишет